# Iniciando um Projeto Vue 2

Tags: vue.js-2

Se eu Quiser-se realizar um projeto em Vue 2 qual template ou bibliotecas seria interessante usar?

Também qual banco de dados, linguagem, framework para backend ou então inteiro em Vue 2 com node?

Digam suas opiniões caso queiram.

Comment: Se quiser fazer um aplicativo multi plataforma (web, mobile e desktop), pode utilizar o [Quasar](http://quasar-framework.org). Caso tenha interesse por [ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/), e criar o projeto usando um template como o da [DevHelp em JS](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter) ou o [Official em TS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já vi alguns *frameworks* de componentes para Vuejs2 e os que mais gostei de trabalhar são:

1. [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/), sendo este um *framework* de componentes com Material Design;

No caso do Vuetify, ele é extremamente completo, basicamente tudo que eu já precisei para a construção de um sistema/site ele possui. 
Possui um fácil entendimento sobre seus componentes. Ótima documentação (bem completa, precisa e consistente). Constantes atualizações (recentemente foi lançado para a versão 1.0.0). Comunidade ativa, sempre contribuindo e auxiliando. E também, eu gosto muito do visual Material, então acaba sendo mais um bônus.

2. [Buefy](https://buefy.github.io/) (*Framework* UI baseado no Bulma) + [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) (*Framework* CSS baseado em *Flexbox*).

No caso do Buefy, existem bem menos componentes, porém sua utilização e a quantidade de código necessária acaba sendo bem menor e mais simples ao meu ver, mas ele dá conta do recado. Utilizo-o para sites que possuem seu visual customizado, ou seja, não pode ser *Flat*, *Material*, etc. Ele trabalha diretamente com o Bulma, onde há elementos que são trabalhados apenas como classes no Bulma, não sendo customizado no Buefy, ao contrário do Vuetify, como por exemplo, não há um `b-button` do Buefy, o botão você não encontrará no Buefy e sim no Bulma, sendo ele apenas uma classe para manter o visual, onde você encontra na aba *Elements* dentro do Bulma.

No caso do Bulma, sua sintaxe é semelhante a um bootstrap, porém ainda mais simples, sendo tudo escrito basicamente com *is* ou *has*, como, por exemplo: *is-size-1*, *has-text-grey*. Bem simples, claro, rápida curva de aprendizado para você e os membros da equipe. Também é baseado em flexbox, e sua utilização para sistemas responsivos também é bem simples.

**Templates e bibliotecas**

No caso de Templates e bibliotecas, é complicado dizer quais utilizar, irá realmente variar de projeto à projeto. Utilizando yarn ou npm, você instalará as dependências de acordo com a necessidade. Trabalhando os *frameworks* citados anteriormente, eu gosto de utilizar pré-processadores de css como o [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) ou [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/), onde eles fornecem uma maior legibilidade do seu CSS,um reaproveitamento de CSS, possibilidade de usar metodologias de css mais facilmente, como [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/), entre outras possibilidades. Outra dependência que usualmente instalo é o [PUG](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), um pré-processador de HTML, que é semelhante ao de CSS, onde no caso do HTML as tags sabem que uma está dentro da outra pela sua identação, e não há fechamento de tags. Eu particularmente recomendo pelo fato de que no caso do Vuejs 2, o HTML geralmente fica no mesmo código que o CSS e o JS. Sem o fechamento de tags, você reduz drásticamente em alguns casos a quantidade de linhas em sua tag `<template>`. Há também diversas outras vantagens, como a não necessidade de escrever divs e sim classes diretamente, e acho que o código fica menor e mais claro de realizar uma manutenção no mesmo. Alguns dizem que o maior problema do PUG é quando o `<template>` fica grande, mas eu acho que se em um componente Vuejs você possui um `<template>` muito grande, você provavelmente fez algo de errado, e ele poderia ser "dividido" em outros componentes menores.

**Banco de dados e linguagem back-end**

Sou desenvolvedor front-end, então não tenho grande conhecimento nesta área, porém vejo que também a escolha de ambas é de acordo com o projeto. Com Vuejs2 eu gosto de trabalhar com o [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) 5.5+, pois é um *framework* extremamente completo e aceito pela comunidade, e possui uma ótima compatibilidade entre ambos. Em pouco tempo, você consegue fazer uma API para um CRUD (por exemplo), com migrations para o banco de dados, autenticação, etc. Há também como realizar testes automatizados com mocks (*Factorys*), utilizando o `phpunit`, garantindo que seu back-end funcione da maneira esperada. Também ele possui o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) que é um gerenciador de pacotes, onde você encontrará ótimos pacotes mediante sua necessidade.

No caso do Nodejs que você comentou, já utilizei brevemente o [Adonisjs](https://adonisjs.com/), sendo este um *framework* para Nodejs que na minha opinião oferece praticamente as mesmas vantagens do Laravel, mas com as vantagens do Nodejs.

Comment: Valeu cara, Vou tentar esses frameworks e dicas que você deu.

Comment: @Caslokman Se possível, aceite com a melhor resposta de gostou da mesma. Obrigado.